# time data '2014-01' does not match format '%y-%m'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

im new to this python, and i want to convert `month` column from `object` to `date` in jupyter notebook using python.

Here is my dataframe :

```
Month   Fee
2014-01 350800
2014-02 113800
2014-03 375200
2014-04 142200
2014-05 304500
```

and the code is :

`df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format = '%y-%m')`

can anyone explain what is wrong with my code? cause i think the format was correct with year and month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `%y` into `%Y`, because `%y` is intended to be used for years written in the `YY` short form (like `14` for `2014`), while `%Y` for the extended `YYYY` years (`2014`).

Try using:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format = '%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

`%y` is Year, short version, without century ,but full year should use `%Y`